# Running Bebop_Autonomy in a Docker Container

Tags: ros, bebop-autonomy, docker, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to run bebop_autonomy in a Docker for Windows container. If I run it on a linux host system in our lab with --network=host, it seems fine. Everything works out, I can start the node up, and I can view the stream using the web_video_server node. However, when I try to run the node in the windows container, I get a -11 error with "No Acks received" back. I'm trying to set it up so that the network is bridged instead of NAT, but I can't figure out how to do it. Is this even possible to do, or should I stick to developing on linux for now? I'm guessing the container just isn't getting the packets and it isn't a problem with my container's code, but that could be the problem as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258942/running-bebop_autonomy-in-a-docker-container/) by [Mabecr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29986/mabecr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-04-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-04-11**:
You're not talking about Docker for *Windows Server* here, correct?

**Comment by [Mabecr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29986/mabecr/) on 2017-04-11**:
No. Docker released a version made to run on a windows machines called Docker for Windows. It can be found on their website. (I'm on mobile at the moment, so I can't link it.) Docker on Linux does exactly what I need, but Docker for Windows either needs to be configured differently or doesn't work.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-04-12**:\

> Docker released a version made to run on a windows machines called Docker for Windows

I know. I was just making sure.

Docker for Windows has the 'docker server' as they call it running in a VM. That is going to complicate things considerably, especially with NAT involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up achieving what I wanted by going into the Hyper-V manager, creating a network that uses an external wifi-adapter, and telling the container to use that instead. Very weird and janky, bur it works correctly. It's possible to run bebop_autonomy in a container on Windows.

---

Originally posted by [Mabecr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29986/mabecr/) with karma: 51 on 2017-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0